# Espaço de Alocação para Campos MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, alocação

Primeiro eu crio o modelo na minha aplicação, depois o Entity Framework gera o SQL para a criação da tabela. A primeira declaração gera uma coluna com o tipo `varchar(20)`, já a segunda gera como `longtext`.

**Exemplo**

```
[StringLength(20)]
public string Codigo { get; set; }

public string CodigoDois { get; set; }
```

**Dúvidas**

Existe alguma diferença entre essas duas declarações(falando sobre alocação de espaço no banco de dados)?
Mesmo se elas armazenarem o mesmo valor como "teste" que tem 6 caracteres?

Se eu sei que um campo possui uma variação do seu comprimento, vamos dizer que entre 10-15 caracteres, seria a melhor decisão limitar para o comprimento máximo ou deixar "sem limite"(falando sobre alocação de espaço no banco de dados)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando o Entity Framework gera as tabelas no seu banco de dados ele verificar os tipos de cada campo, no caso do tipo STRING quando você especificar o tamanho ele faz a mesma especificação para o banco com seu tipo correspondente.

No caso do seu

```
[StringLength(20)]
public string Codigo { get; set; }
```

O correspondente no MySQL é o varchar(20), mas quando o mesmo tipo string e declarado sem um tamanho fixo o Entity Framework alocar o máximo possível para esse tipo no banco de dados que no caso do MySQL e o longtext.

As colunas do tipo BLOB como o LONGTEXT são inerentemente comprimento variável e ocupam quase nenhum armazenamento quando não usado. O espaço necessário por eles mesmo não é afetado no caso de um NULL valor, no caso de um uso como o texto `"teste"` a alocação e definida no tamanho da string passada.

***Vantagens / desvantagens de BLOBs vs. VARCHARs***

Todos os comentários neste parágrafo relativo tipo VARCHAR são válidos para o tipo CHAR também.
Cada comentário termina com BLOB + ou VARCHAR + marca para indicar que tipo de dados é melhor.

---

- Você sabe comprimento máximo de seus dados?

Com VARCHARs você precisa declarar o comprimento máximo da cadeia .
Com blobs você não precisa se ​​preocupar com isso .
BLOB +

---

- Você precisa armazenar cadeias muito longas ?

Uma única coluna VARCHAR se restringe a 32K bytes (isto é, cerca de 10 mil caracteres Unicode) .
O tamanho máximo blob é (de acordo com o Guia de Uso);

- tamanho da página 1kb => 64 Mb
- tamanho da página 2kb => 512 Mb
- tamanho de página de 4 KB => 4 Gb
- tamanho de página de 8 KB => 32 Gb

BLOB +

---

- Você precisa armazenar muitas colunas de texto longo na única tabela?

O comprimento de linha total (não comprimido) é restrito a 64 k. VARCHARs são armazenadas em linha diretamente, de modo que você não pode armazenar muitas cadeias longas em uma linha.
Blobs são representados por seu blob-id, assim usa-se apenas 8 bytes de 64K máxima.
BLOB +

---

- Você quer minimizar a chamada entre cliente e servidor ?

Dados VARCHAR são buscados junto com outros dados de linha em uma operação de busca e, normalmente, várias linhas são enviados através da rede ao mesmo tempo.
Cada único blob precisa fazer extra operação de busca `open/fetch`.
VARCHAR +

---

- Você quer minimizar a quantidade de dados transferidos entre cliente e servidor ?

A vantagem de blobs é que ao buscar a linha que você obter apenas blob-id, para que possa decidir se quer buscar dados blob ou não.
Em versões mais antigas do InterBase havia um problema que VARCHARs foram enviados através da rede no comprimento declarado completo. Este problema já foi corrigido no Firebird 1.5 e InterBase 6.5.
desenhar (BLOB + para versões mais antigas do servidor )

---

- Você quer minimizar o espaço usado?

VARCHARs são RLE comprimido (de fato linha inteira são comprimidas, exceto blobs). No máximo 128 bytes pode ser comprimido a 2 bytes. Isto significa que, mesmo vazio VARCHAR (32000) vai ocupar 500 + 2 bytes.

Blobs não são compactados, mas vazio (ou seja null) blob vai ocupar apenas 8 bytes de blob-id (e será mais tarde RLE comprimido). blob não-vazia podem ser armazenados na mesma página como outros dados da linha (se couber), ou na página separada. Pequeno blob que se encaixa na página de dados tem sobrecarga de cerca de 40 bytes (ou um pouco mais). Grande blob tem o mesmo 40 bytes sobrecarga na página de dados, além de 28 bytes sobrecarga em cada página blob (30 bytes na primeira). Uma página blob não pode conter mais de um blob (ou seja, páginas blob não são compartilhadas como páginas de dados). Por exemplo. para 4K tamanho da página, se você armazenar 5K blob, duas páginas do tipo blob serão alocados, o que significa que você perde 3K do espaço! Em outras palavras - o tamanho de página maior, a maior probabilidade de que pequenas blobs vai caber na página de dados, mas também espaço mais desperdício se as páginas blob separados são necessários para grandes blobs.
VARCHAR + (exceto VARCHARs com extremamente grande comprimento declarado, ou tabelas com muitas blobs NULL)

---

- Você precisa de mesa com extremamente grande número de linhas ?

Cada linha é identificado por DB_KEY , que é um valor de 64 bits , 32 bits , onde representa ID relação e 32 bits são utilizados para localizar a linha . número máximo de modo teórico de linhas em uma tabela é 2 ^ 32 (mas por várias razões o verdadeiro máxima é ainda menor ) . Blob -ids são atribuídos a partir do mesmo espaço de endereço como DB_KEYs , isso significa que os mais blobs na tabela , menos DB_KEYs permanecerá para enfrentar filas . Por outro lado , quando as linhas armazenadas são largas (por exemplo se contiverem longo VARCHARs ), então menos linhas caber na página de dados e muitos valores DB_KEY permanecerá unasigned de qualquer maneira.
varchar + ?

---

- Você quer um bom desempenho ?

Porque grandes blobs estão armazenados fora páginas de dados , eles aumentam "densidade" de linhas em páginas de dados e eficiência , assim, cache ( reduzir o número de operações I / O durante a pesquisa).
BLOB +

---

- Você precisa executar a busca sobre o conteúdo das colunas de texto ?

Na coluna VARCHAR você pode usar operadores como '= ', ' >', entre elas, de () , caso sensível como e de partida, caso insensível CONTENDO . Na maioria dos casos índice pode ser usado para acelerar a pesquisa para cima.
Blobs não podem ser indexados , e você está restrito a GOSTO , de partida, e contendo operadores. Você não pode comparar diretamente blobs com os operadores '= ', ' >' etc. ( a menos que você usar UDF) , para que você não pode , por exemplo, unir tabelas em campos Blob.
VARCHAR +

---

- Você deseja pesquisar conteúdo destes textos com CONTENDO ?

Containig pode ser usado para executar a busca case-insensitive de conteúdo do campo VARCHAR . (Sem uso de índice)
Porque não é possível definir ordem de agrupamento para as colunas blob , você não pode usar a pesquisa insensível plenamente caso com caracteres nacionais em colunas blob (somente metade inferior do conjunto de caracteres será case insensitive) . ( Como alternativa , você pode usar UDF ).
Firebird 2 já permite definir agrupamento de texto (e binários) colunas.
VARCHAR +

---

- Você precisa maiúsculas conteúdo da coluna de texto ?

Você pode usar o built-in função UPPER () em VARCHAR , mas não no blob . (Também CAST, MIN , MAX não pode ser usado com blobs )
VARCHAR +

---

Não é possível classificar por coluna blob . (E GROUP BY, DISTINCT , UNION, JOIN ON )
Não é possível para concatenar colunas blob .
VARCHAR +

---

Não há nenhuma função de conversão built-in (CAST ) para converter blob para VARCHAR ou VARCHAR para Blob.
( Mas é possível escrever UDF para este fim . )
Desde Firebird 1.5 é possível usar builtin função SUBSTRING para converter blob para VARCHAR (mas FROM e cláusulas não pode exceder 32K) .
desenhar

---

Não é possível atribuir valor a blob diretamente no comando SQL ,
por exemplo. Inserir valores guia ( MyBlob ) ( 'abc' ); ( Mas é possível usar UDF para converter string para blob ) .
VARCHAR +

Firebird - 0.9.4 já tem essa funcionalidade
desenhar

---

- Você precisa de uma boa segurança nestas colunas de texto ?

Para recuperar os dados da tabela , você precisa ter concedido o privilégio SELECT.
Para recuperar blob, você precisa saber única blob -id ( armazenado na tabela ), mas Firebird / InterBase não irá verificar se você tem quaisquer direitos de mesa blob pertence. Isso significa que todo mundo que sabe ou adivinhar blob -id direito pode ler o blob sem quaisquer direitos à mesa. ( Você pode experimentá-lo com ISQL e comando BLOBDUMP . )
VARCHAR +

---

Você pode ver mais detalhes nos links abaixo

[Referencia 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758857/memory-consumption-of-having-a-column-longtext-in-mysql-database)

[Referencia 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506832/what-is-the-mysql-varchar-max-size)

[Referencia 3](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html)

[Referencia 4](http://mujweb.cz/iprenosil/interbase/ip_ib_strings.htm?redirected=1470073749#_strings_blob_varchar)

Comment: O segundo link ta dando um biziu muito louco, talvez fosse mais interessante postar o link direto pro SO em ingles mesm.

Comment: Opa, não tinha visto .